# Change regex pattern matches with function return value

Tags: php, preg-match, return-value

I have the following variable:

```
$text = 'This is a sentence [url=http://site.com] that contains urls [url=javascript:alert();]';
```

and the following line of code to validate URLs:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[url=([^\\]]+)]/', filter_var('$1', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL), $text);
```

Output:

"This is a sentence that contains urls"

How can I get the following as output?

"This is a sentence http://site.com that contains urls"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = 'This is a sentence [url=http://site.com] that contains urls [url=javascript:alert();]';


function url($url){
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return $url;
    return '';
}


$text = preg_replace('/\[url=([^\\]]+)]/e', 'url("$1")', $text);


echo $text;
```

Comment: great! that's what I needed. However, can you explain how that works? how is it that the function `url()` actually executed within the quotes??

Comment: mine is the old way, yet preg_replace_callback from @H is the new way (5.3+). at old time, php use a string to do callback. like eval(string).

Comment: Also note that `/e` may lead to security vulnerabilities and is deprecated and discouraged: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = 'This is a sentence [url=http://site.com] that contains urls [url=javascript:alert();]';
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[url=([^\\]]+)]/',
    function ($url) {
        $clean = filter_var($url[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        if ($clean) {
            return '<a href="' . $clean . '">' . $clean . '</a>';
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    },
    $text
);
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/Hwgq90

Comment: Note that you would probably still need to html-escape `$clean`.

Comment: sağolasın @Halil ama tam istediğim değil.

Comment: I will see if I can continue on your steps and make it what I need.

Comment: @mavili, validate olmayanlar hiç gelmiyorsun istiyorsun sanırım, update ettim.

Comment: elinize sağlık @HalilÖzgür